# Implementing IBM MQ Listener using WMQ code (not JMS)

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I have a hard time figuring out implementing IBM MQ Listener (on message event) using WMQ jars/code. 
I have seen JMS implementation where we have OnMessage method which gets executed whenever a message is received in a queue.  I am looking for a similar option using WMQ Jars. I am going through MQGetMessageOptions class and MQC options but no luck so far.  Any help would be appreciated.

I am using **com.ibm.mq-6.0.2.1.jar**  jar file.

Comment: First: IBM MQ 6.0 has been out of support from IBM since September 30th 2012 (over 7 years).  Why don't you use a more recent supported version.   For example TLS 1.2 is not supported at that level nor is bidirectional heat beats.   That level also requires multiple jar files.  Recent supported versions only require one IBM MQ jar (`com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar`) along with 1 to 3 other Oracle jars if you use the JMS API.

Comment: IBM MQ server is running on 8.0 and will be migrated to 9.0 before april.  The jar I mentioned is just client jar

Comment: Right and all that I mentioned is related to the client jar. Your other question was would it work. As stated in Morag's answer it will only support features that existed as of that level. There are many many improvements both functionality and security between v6.0 and v9.1. If you are working on a new application it would be unthinkable to use that old of a version (6.0).

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc.  Understand that IBM MQ classes for Java doesn't have the feature to listen to queue. (till 8.0)  and recommended way is to use IBM MQ classes for JMS.  Thanks for the clarification. So conclusion is it is not possible to implement this feature with WMQ code?

Comment: IBM MQ classes for Java does not support it even at v8.0 or later and never will unless IBM has a change if heart regarding there stabilization announcement noted above.

Comment: Thanks. So to summarize , it is not possible with IBM MQ classes for java at any version.  Correct?

Comment: Not to use a call back type method.   You would need to poll the queue looking for messages instead of registering to MQ to provide you messages as they are put to the queue.

Comment: Polling is very expensive and it is not a proper listener. So the answer is it is not possible to implement a MQ listener using IBM MQ classes for Java. Only way is to use IBM MQ classes for JMS. Correct?

Comment: Yes.. I will accept.. Go ahead.. Mention clearly in your answer that it is not possible with IBM MQ classes for java so for people who read is easier to understand on summary.

Comment: Use "get with wait" which will substantially reduce polling for messages in a queue,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary**:

IBM MQ classes for JMS implement asynchronous message listener functionality (onMessage) using the underlying IBM MQ callback functionality since IBM MQ v7.0.

The IBM MQ classes for Java do not support asynchronous message listener functionality (callback) at all.

---

**Background**

Callback functionality was added to IBM MQ at v7.0 but IBM did not implement this feature in IBM MQ classes for Java.

Please note that per the v9.0 Knowledge center page "[Using IBM MQ classes for Java](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030520_.htm)", IBM MQ Classes for Java have been functionally stabilized at the level shipped in IBM MQ Version 8.0. Since IBM MQ classes for Java didn't have this feature as of IBM MQ  v8.0, it will not be added by IBM unless they change direction.

The next step after IBM stabilizes a feature is deprecating the feature. It would not be advised to develop new applications with IBM MQ classes for Java, better to go with IBM MQ classes for JMS.

---

**Alternative**

If you really have a need to use IBM MQ classes for Java, you would need to poll the queue looking for messages instead of registering a callback to MQ.  Note that since callback did not exist prior to MQ v7.0 the IBM MQ classes for JMS asynchronous message listener at MQ v6.0 and lower was implemented by polling the queue in background. IBM has always supported GET with a wait. Doing a simple loop that does a get with a wait of X amount of time, will only need to reach out to the queue manager as often as the wait times out or a new message lands on the queue.

If you do a GET without a wait and then immediately do another GET without a wait, then this would be both expensive and not a recommended solution.

The nice thing about a IBM MQ classes for JMS asynchronous message listener is that IBM has taken care of the hard work, you only need to write code to process the message, not the logic to obtain the message. Using the IBM MQ classes for JMS asynchronous message listener is in my opinion still a better approach than a properly written polling application because if nothing else you are not reinventing the wheel.

---

**Other APIs**

There are of course other non-Java APIs that support callback.

- In C#, it has a similar situation, the original MQ.NET API (`amqmdnet.dll`) does not support callback, but the newer XMS.NET API (JMS like implementation in .NET) does support callback.
- The normal C API supports callback, but C++ does not. Anything that uses the C API libraries could technically support callback if they expose that functionality, but some things do not, for example pymqi is based on the C API libraries but does not support callback.